# Why $E=\{(x,\alpha)\mid 0\leq \alpha\leq |f(x)|\}$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f$ is measurable, why $E=\{(x,\alpha)\mid 0\leq \alpha\leq |f(x)|\}$ is measurable ? to me is by definition but my teacher asked me to prove it (and so that it's not a definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** write $E$ in terms of the sets $E_\beta = \{ x: f(x)\le \beta \}$.

---

\begin{align}
\{ x: -\alpha \le f(x) \le \alpha \}
&= \{ x: -\alpha \le f(x)  \} \cap \{ x: f(x) \le \alpha \}
\\&= \{ x: f(x) \le \alpha \} \cap \left\{ x:  f(x) < -\alpha \right\}^c
\\&= \{ x: f(x) \le \alpha \} \cap 
\left[\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left\{ x:  f(x) < -\alpha + \frac 1n \right\}\right]^c
\\&= E_\alpha \cap  \left[ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_{\alpha - \frac 1n}\right]^c
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, so can I use the argument: since $f$ is measurable, $|f|$ is also measurable and so, $E_\alpha=\{x\mid |f(x)|\geq \alpha\geq 0\}$ is also measurable. We conclude that $$\{(x,\alpha)\mid 0\leq\alpha\leq |f(x)|\}=\bigcup_{\alpha}E_\alpha$$ is measurable. That correct ?

Comment: on the RHS it does not depend on $\alpha$. hence it is wrong.

Comment: @idm see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

- The map $F:=(x,\alpha)\mapsto (\alpha,|f(x)|)$ is measurable since so are the projection $(x,\alpha)\mapsto \alpha$ and $(x,\alpha)\mapsto |f(x)|$.
- The set $S:=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb R,0\leqslant a\leqslant b\}$ is Borel measurable.
- To conclude, notice that $E=F^{-1}(S)$.